# How to verify Google Play Services

Tags: libgdx, google-play-services

Im trying to figure that out for a few days now, but i can't find some good example about the problem. I think i have founded good code example, but i dont know where/how to use it.

About the problem: whenever app comes from foreground i would like to check if the Google play services are avalable. So for that i want use this code:

```
static final int REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_PLAY_SERVICES = 1001;

private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(status)) {
            showErrorDialog(status);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "This device is not supported.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void showErrorDialog(int code) {
    GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(code, this,REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_PLAY_SERVICES).show();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  switch (requestCode) {
    case REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_PLAY_SERVICES:
      if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play Services must be installed.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
      }
      return;
  }
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

now i would like to check the services with

```
if (checkPlayServices()) {
    System.out.println("ok");
}
```

but where? I have tryed to use that code in class that extends the game, but then

int status = **GooglePlayServicesUtil**.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

path cant be found. On the other hand, when i place it in separate activity

```
public class AuthActivity extends Activity {
    //all previous code
}
```

path is ok. Does someone have any idea how to work that out?

Answer (score 1):

**Answer**: Because this is Android-specific code, you must use that code in the Android module (containing the `Activity` class), not in the Core module (containing the class that extends `Game`).

**Reason**: If you put that function in the Core module, there is no library dependency of `GooglePlayServicesUtil` for the Core module, hence you cannot refer to the class `GooglePlayServicesUtil`. Read more on [this](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code) link for using Android-specific code.